# Why django not able to extend project level template?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-1.8

This is my directory:

```
myproject/
├── frontpage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── intrafish
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── myproject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── base.pyc
│   │   ├── development.py
│   │   ├── development.pyc
│   │   └── production.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── templates
    └── base.html
```

I am trying to extend base.html inside index.html in frontpage app.
My base.html:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load url from future %}
{% load staticfiles %}


{% block header %} {% endblock %}
```

My index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

My wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "makemeacurry.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "makemeacurry.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I definitely feel that it is because I segregated my settings in different files and thus this is happening.

My template in base.py which I inherit in development.py using `from .base import *` settings:

```
# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',

            ],
            'debug': True,
        },
    },
]
```

How could I make this work?

Thanks

---------- ## Edit 1 ##

This is the error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /

base.html
```

and here is what template postmortem looks like:

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

```
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
    /Users/myuser/projects/myproject/myproject/templates/base.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
    /Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html (File does not exist)
    /Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/base.html (File does not exist)
    /Users/myuser/projects/myproject/frontpage/templates/base.html (File does not exist)
```

Comment: You haven't said what is happening, or where those "template settings" are and how they relate to the other settings files.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated my answer with edits, those template settings are in base.py and on development.py I am just doing from .base import *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your settings files are in a subdirectory, so BASE_DIR is no longer being calculated correctly; you need to add another level.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname((os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...solved it...but do you have any suggestion for wsgi.py and manage.py setting default env config?

Comment: No, because I don't know what you mean by "setting default env config".

Comment: I meant this line os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "makemeacurry.settings") is it right? It is in both wsgi.py and manage.py. And I run using gunicorn.